# Why am I still getting a 401(Unauthorized) error from api get request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, get, axios

I have an example of trying to get some videos from a channel in react using axios and get request to the api. Everything looks good but when It compiles, I get a console error that states: GET `https://api.vimeo.com/channels/180097/videos/&key=*********** 401 (Authorization Required`

The access token is the correct one generated when I registered it. Here's the code set up:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = '***********************';

class Apicall extends Component {

   componentDidMount() {
       this.getChannel();
   }

   getChannel() {
        axios.get(`https://api.vimeo.com/channels/180097/videos/&key=${API_KEY}`) 
    .then(res => {
        const videos = res.data.data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
        this.setState({videos});
      });
   }

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);

      this.state = {
        channel_id: '180097',
        data: [],
        videos: [],
        per_page: '5',
        paging: {
            first: '/channels/180097/videos?page=1',
            last: '/channels/180097/videos?page=3' 
        }
    }
    this.getChannel = this.getChannel.bind(this);
}

render(){
    return (
         <div className="container">
           <h1></h1>
           <ul>
               {this.state.videos.map(video => 
                  <li key={video.uri}></li>
               )}
           </ul>
         </div>
       );
    }
 }
 export default Apicall;
```

Why is it still not getting the access token?

Comment: I may be wrong, but i think the url has an extra slash.axios.get(`https://api.vimeo.com/channels/180097/videos/&key=${API_KEY}`)    -- should be axios.get(`https://api.vimeo.com/channels/180097/videos&key=${API_KEY}`)  right?

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending the access token in the headers rather than the URL? https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#best-practices

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst I just did as the documentation states in the command line and it gave me: Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Authorization: Bearer ***************** " value of
type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".

Comment: @KirkLarkin  I just did as the documentation states in the command line and it gave me: Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Authorization: Bearer ***************** " value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary". I have no idea why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to make a post request to `https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client` with your `Authorization` header set to `Basic Auth`, your username is your application `client identifier` and your password is `your client secret`. So `Authentication: Basic base64(<client-identifier>:<client-secret>)`. You'll also need to set `grant_type` to `client_credentials`

You'll then get a reply like:

```
{
    "access_token": "dd339558163d867d92f4616ca06<redacted>",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "scope": "public private",
    "app": {
        "name": "test",
        "uri": "/apps/<app_id>"
    }
}
```

The `access_token` can then be used for following requests:

You make a request to https://api.vimeo.com/channels/180097 with the `Authorization` header set to `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>`

Axios will be something like this:

```
axios.post('https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client',
        { grant_type: 'client_credentials' },
        { headers: { Authorization: 'Basic btoa(<client-identifier>:<client-secret>)' } })

axios.get('https://api.vimeo.com/channels/180097',
    { headers: { Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' } })
```

Granted, this took me a while to find out because the vimeo api documentation is pretty bad.

Postman export in xhr:

```
var data = "grant_type=client_credentials";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic <insert_base64_of_client_id_and_client_secret>");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "e13df60c-a625-411d-8020-a51086e60838");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.send(data);
```

---

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.vimeo.com/channels/180097");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <insert_access_token>");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Postman-Token", "5f32ac6c-2c86-4fbc-a7cb-43c8b01f7ea7");

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You’ll need to update your question with more information to see where you’re having problems then. The requests above have been built using Postman, so it should be more of an implementation issue.

Comment: That’s not the issue, postman is a tool for testing HTTP requests. If it works there your problem lies elsewhere. But I can’t help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Ok ok. here is a fiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/mlegemah/n5u2wwjg/157040/

Comment: There isn't any JavaScript code in your fiddle. I made a sandbox with an example https://codesandbox.io/s/pwro9p7w8j. The render function might be broken because the vimeo api temporarily blocked me after too many requests and I couldn't test it. Enter your client identifier and client_secret at the top of the file.

Comment: so weird I thought I added it

Comment: that works now I'm gonna work on getting them to display in the vimeo player